# How can I show/hide a JSF datatable column with ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, datatable

I have an ajax call that refreshes the following table.  Can I have the "Score" column (it is a BigDecimal) hidden if all values are null, otherwise it should display?

```
<h:dataTable id="theTable" value="#{MyBean.people}" var="person">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Name" />
    </f:facet>
    #{person.name}
  </h:column> 
  <h:column rendered="#{person.score != null}">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="The Score" />
    </f:facet>
    #{person.score}
  </h:column> 
</h:dataTable>
```

The current rendered always makes the column NOT render, even when the scores are not null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "easy" way to do that, you have to look at the complete collection yourself. You could write helper method that checks your list for null values:

```
public boolean isAllScoresNull() {
    for(Person p : people) {
        if(p.getScore != null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and use that via EL in your page:

```
...
<h:column rendered="#{myBeanController.allScoresNull}">
...
```

You could also define a TagFunction for that task.

Comment: on second thought, you might want to use something like org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(people) to check the List in the sample above...

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if creating a separate method on the Bean was a possible solution.

Comment: @Ryan, creating a seperate method on the bean is a design question, i guess... Glad to help!

Comment: @dnno Sorry but, when I `update` datatable with `<p:ajax>` (attached to certain `commandButton`) it `does NOT hide datatable` (when command button pressed and `listener` invoked, there I've checked the `list` and set `rendered = "#{controller.dataFound}"` to approp. boolean value). Is there a solution to that?